# How can I access a local network namespace from an external node?

Tags: routing, bridge, network-namespaces

I am trying to set up a runc container running mongoDB Enterprise Edition v4.4 on an EC2 Ubuntu x86 20.04 node, kernel v5.10. I am using the following to set up a network namespace for the container:

```
sudo brctl addbr runc0
sudo ip link set runc0 up
sudo ip addr add 192.168.10.1/24 dev runc0
sudo ip link add name veth-host type veth peer name veth-guest
sudo ip link set veth-host up
sudo brctl addif runc0 veth-host
sudo ip netns add mongo_enter
sudo ip link set veth-guest netns runc
sudo ip netns exec mongo_enter ip link set veth-guest name eth1
sudo ip netns exec mongo_enter ip addr add 192.168.10.101/24 dev eth1
sudo ip netns exec mongo_enter ip link set eth1 up
sudo ip netns exec mongo_enter ip route add default via 192.168.10.1
```

What I want to do is access the runc mongo server running in this namespace from an external node, not necessarily in the same network. I tried setting an IP for the namespace and bridge similar to the private IP of the EC2 instance, but got the following error:

```
Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway
```

Is this the correct way to set up the namespace, or is there another simpler/correct/standard way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's the correct way to set up a namespace, but:

Network namespaces basically work like different computers connected via a LAN cable (the veth pair), so you need to setup proper routing, **in particular** in the originating and intermediate nodes.

If you control the "external node, not necessarily in the same network" and everything between this node and your container, then that's doable. If not, you need to pretend that the container network namespace "externally" is reachable under the same IP as the main network namespace, which means you need to set up port forwarding (google, there's plenty of tutorials).